# Div's hover tilt

Tags: html, css, hover

I have 2 div, i'm trying to hide the first, and display the second using the hover, but I can't see the second div, because the first one go in a cycle of display none and block.

That's the snippet

http://codepen.io/IvanPalma/pen/qbOLJp?editors=110

```css
.item-inner {
    background: red;
    width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
    z-index: 99;
}

.item-inner:hover {
  display: none;
}

.item-inner-hover {
  display:none;
}

.item-inner.hover:hover {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-inner"></div>
<div class="item-inner-hover"></div>
```

Comment: use toggle on hover. or show hide function.

Comment: Shouldn't `item-inner-hover` be inside `item-inner`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use opacity instead of display with the divs stacked on top of each other.

```
.item-inner {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  opacity:1;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
}

.item-inner:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.item-inner-hover {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **Pure CSS** solution then see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Leo_the_lion/4p8CM/2407/). you just have to take both div in **one parent div** and then change the css on the hover of parent and just switch `display:none` to `display:block.`

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the two DIVs inside another one, so when you hover the parent you can access its children :

**HTML :**

```
<div class="outer">
  <div class="item-inner"></div>
  <div class="item-inner-hover"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS :**

```
.outer  {
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
.item-inner {
  display:block;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;  
}

.item-inner-hover {
  display:none !important;  
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.outer:hover .item-inner {
    display: none !important;
}
.outer:hover .item-inner-hover {
    display: block !important;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

**Snippet :**
http://codepen.io/pen/KVdJby

Answer (score 0):

To place them above each other, both need to have `position: absolute;`, the top one (`.item-inner`) with a higher `z-index` value. The bottom one (`.item-inner-hover`) doesn't need a hover setting since it simply becomes visible if the top one becomes invisible.

```
.item-inner {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 99;
  display: block;
}

.item-inner:hover {
  opacity: 0.0;
}

.item-inner-hover {
  position: absolute;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 50;
}
```

EDIT: `opacity: 0.0` is better for the hover state, since `display: none` actually removes the DIV from the display, which doesn't work well for the hovering.

New fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKaLzQ?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.item-inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

.item-inner-hover {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

.item-inner:hover .item-inner-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-inner">
  <div class="item-inner-hover"></div>
</div>
```

Or if you want to keep divs as siblings you can do this

```css
.item-inner {
  background: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-inner-hover{
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
  display: inline-block;
}

.item-inner:hover ~ .item-inner-hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.item-inner:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="item-inner"></div>
<div class="item-inner-hover"></div>
```